# text-shadow CSS en dispositivos moviles

Tags: css, css3

He realizado un efecto de neon en texto en una web, en la web funciona correctamente pero en dispositivos moviles como android o ios este efecto no se muestra.

el codigo del efecto es:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #F00, 0 0 70px #F00, 0 0 80px #F00, 0 0 100px #F00, 0 0 150px #F00;
```

alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: mira salvo que las versiones de los navegadores móviles sean muy viejas no deberías tener problemas checa su grado de adopción en caniuse https://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow

Comment: los navegadores estan actualizados a la ultima version, aun asi no funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar un [mcve]? Sin eso no tenemos mas idea que tu del error

Comment: http://traviesoclub.com